# Error on Sequelize Many to Many association - AggregateError

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have the following model design in my app:

```
@Table({ freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'Business', timestamps: true})
export class Business extends Model<Business> {

  @Unique(true)
  @Column(DataType.STRING(255))
  businessName: string;

  @Default(BusinessStatusEnum.pending_verify)
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.ENUM(BusinessStatusEnum.active, BusinessStatusEnum.canceled, BusinessStatusEnum.pending_payment, BusinessStatusEnum.pending_verify))
  businessStatus: string;

  @AllowNull(true)
  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  businessVerificationMessageId: string;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Default(false)
  @Column(DataType.BOOLEAN)
  businessVerifiedEmail: boolean;

  // Many to Many association

  @BelongsToMany(() => SubscriptionPlan, () => BusinessSubscriptionPlan)
  subscriptionPlans: SubscriptionPlan[];

  @HasMany(() => BusinessSubscriptionPlan)
  businessSubscriptionPlans: BusinessSubscriptionPlan[];

}


@Table({ freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'SubscriptionPlan', timestamps: true})
export class SubscriptionPlan extends Model<SubscriptionPlan> {

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Unique(true)
  @Column(DataType.STRING(255))
  subscriptionPlanName: string;

  // Many to Many association

  @BelongsToMany(() => Business, () => BusinessSubscriptionPlan)
  businesses: Business[];

  @HasMany(() => BusinessSubscriptionPlan)
  businessSubscriptionPlans: BusinessSubscriptionPlan[];

}

@Table({ freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'BusinessSubscriptionPlan', timestamps: true})
export class BusinessSubscriptionPlan extends Model<BusinessSubscriptionPlan> {

  @PrimaryKey
  @AllowNull(false)
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  id: number;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.ENUM(BusinessSubscriptionPeriodEnum.monthly, BusinessSubscriptionPeriodEnum.annual))
  businessSubscriptionPeriod: string;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column(DataType.ENUM(BusinessSubscriptionPlanStatusEnum.active, BusinessSubscriptionPlanStatusEnum.upgraded, BusinessSubscriptionPlanStatusEnum.canceled))
  businessSubscriptionStatus: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => Business)
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  businessId: number

  @BelongsTo(() => Business, 'businessId')
  business: Business;

  @ForeignKey(() => SubscriptionPlan)
  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  subscriptionPlanId: number

  @BelongsTo(() => SubscriptionPlan, 'subscriptionPlanId')
  subscriptionPlan: SubscriptionPlan;

  @HasMany(() => PaymentReceipt )
  paymentReceipts: PaymentReceipt[];

}
```

In my code I'm trying to save a business object and the relationship table between Business and SubscriptionPlan.

```
try {
                    business.isNewRecord = true;
                    const savedBusiness = await business.save();
                    await savedBusiness.reload();
                    if (subscriptionPlan && businessSubscriptionPlan) {
                        savedBusiness.addSubscriptionPlan(subscriptionPlan, { through: businessSubscriptionPlan });
                    }
                    return savedBusiness;
                } catch (error) {
                    throw new CustomError(messages[2].message.replace("${object}", "Business"), 500, error);
            }
```

I'm getting this error

> (node:9252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AggregateError
> at recursiveBulkCreate (/home/jose/Documents/prop-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:2600:17)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> at async Function.bulkCreate (/home/jose/Documents/prop-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:2824:12)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)
> at async BelongsToMany.add (/home/jose/Documents/prop-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js:740:30)
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> <node_internals>/internal/process/warning.js:42
> (node:9252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
> <node_internals>/internal/process/warning.js:42
> (node:9252) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I don't know if I have something wrong on my model or is in the actual code that save the business, in the model I followed this documentation https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html
I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, it seems like the problem was in this line

```
@Table({ freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'BusinessSubscriptionPlan', timestamps: true})
```

I removed the timestamps from the the through table and also change the code that save the business to pass a literal object instead the model object.

```
business.isNewRecord = true;
                    const savedBusiness = await business.save();
                    await savedBusiness.reload();
                    if (subscriptionPlan && businessSubscriptionPlan) {
                        savedBusiness.addSubscriptionPlan(subscriptionPlan, { through: {
                            businessSubscriptionPeriod: businessSubscriptionPlan.businessSubscriptionPeriod,
                            businessSubscriptionStatus: businessSubscriptionPlan.businessSubscriptionStatus
                        } });
                    }
```